# how to check whether an vector of boolean contains false or not?

Tags: clojure

Why the following returns false? I expect it should return true since one element of the vector is really false

```
user=> (contains? [1 false] false)
false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[contains?](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/contains_q) checks for the presence of a *key* in an associative collection. `false` is a *value*, not a key, in `[1 false]`. Only `0` and `1` are keys. You should use:

```
(some false? [1 false])
```